# Can't get sed command to work in inline file update mode

Tags: linux, bash, sed

This sed command works when output to the terminal:

```
for FILE in *.cs; do NEW_VERS="$(cat $FILE | awk '/%version:/{print $(NF-1)}')"; sed -e "/Revision.*/,/using/{/\/\/.[\*]*[\*]$/i \\/\/  $NEW_VERS      221203  berra tjing tjong." -e '}' $FILE; done
```

Tried inline file update with "i", but it doesn't work:

```
for FILE in *.cs; do NEW_VERS="$(cat $FILE | awk '/%version:/{print $(NF-1)}')"; sed -ie "/Revision.*/,/using/{/\/\/.[\*]*[\*]$/i \\/\/  $NEW_VERS      221203  berra tjing tjong." -e '}' $FILE; done
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unexpected `}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unexpected `}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unexpected `}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unexpected `}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unexpected `}'
```

What command changes have to be done to get it to work updating file inline, within the loop?

What it does:

The command look for a block with starting pattern "Revision.*", and end pattern "using".
In this block look for a line like "// ***************", and adding following line above:
$NEW_VERS      221203  berra tjing tjong.

Where $NEW_VERS will be a parsed version.

All this works fine with the first command, terminal output.
But I want to get it to work edit files inline.

Thanks

Comment: At least for GNU sed, `-ie` is not the same as `-i -e`

Comment: Thanks you!  :-)   That was an easy one when you know it....

Comment: Just as a general note, it's bad practice to use CAPS for shell script variables since by convention, the global environment variables are capitalized and this can lead to naming collisions and weird bugs. Also, you could greatly simplify your `sed` by using a different delimiter for the `s` command and there is no need to escape the `*` if they are in a character class. Either put them in a class, or escape them, not both. For example: `sed 's|foo[*]|new|'`. Oh, and there's no need for cat either: `nvers=$(awk '/%version:/{print $(NF-1)}' "$file")`.